# How update in real time with highcharts 3 data module?

Tags: csv, highcharts, real-time, beta

With the new data module of highcharts 3 (http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released) I wonder how update in real time each time the data change. I try with `chart.redraw()` after update the div with the data, but nothing happend.

I understand that exist the manual way of do changes as the demos on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update, but think using the data module is easier IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post. The author solves a similiar problem with a periodical re-data and the redraw()-method of highcharts-component:
http://liewdaryl.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/real-time-html-charting-from-csv-data-source/

Answer (score 1):

You can always recreate chart:

```
$('#container').highcharts().destroy();
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv1').innerHTML
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Categorized CSV data'
    }
});
```